# Invalid operation at current cursor position

Tags: java, sql

I made a Java Forum and im trying to search my sql table, when i click the button to finally search it (the name of the person) it comes up with a "Invalid Operation at Current Cursor Position" error.

Here'e my code for the search button. Please help me figure this out.

---

```
private void firstSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try{
        String fname = searchText.getText();
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees",
            "users", "admin");
        PreparedStatement pState = connect.prepareStatement("select * from WORKERS where First_Name = ?");
        pState.setString(1,fname);
        ResultSet rSet;
        rSet = pState.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            int id_col = rSet.getInt("Employee_ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first = rSet.getString("First_Name");
            String last = rSet.getString("Last_Name");
            String job = rSet.getString("Title");
            String hireDate = rSet.getString("Hire_Date");
            textID.setText(id);
            textFirstName.setText(first);
            textLastName.setText(last);
            textTitle.setText(job);
            textHireDate.setText(hireDate);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not in Database");
        }
    }catch(SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(employees.this, err.getMessage());
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
    ResultSet rSet;
    rSet = pState.executeQuery();
```

instead of

```
    if(rs.next()){
```

use

```
if(rSet.next()){
```

Here `resultset` object is `rSet` not `rs`

Comment: Im an idiot lol thank you!